How to join 2 collections with array of string object ID mongodb
I have a collection called store
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "64f885a4758688440f24d070"
  },
  "name": "Test Location",
  "Tags": [
    "66249849f94df523bfb6324d",
    "6624984ff94df523bfb6324e"
  ],
  "updatedAt": {
    "$date": "2024-07-23T22:30:38.454Z"
  }
}

And I have a Tag collection
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "66249849f94df523bfb6324d"
  },
  "name": "Night",
}

{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "6624984ff94df523bfb6324e"
  },
  "name": "Bar",
}

I would like to join 2 collections with tag ids to something like
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "64f885a4758688440f24d070"
  },
  "name": "Test Location",
  "Tags": [
    "66249849f94df523bfb6324d",
    "6624984ff94df523bfb6324e"
  ],
  "TagResult": [
     {"name": "Night"},
     {"name": "Bar"},
  ] 
}


Any help is appreciated.

You probably had a failed attempt with $lookup since you have a mismatch in the datatypes of the 2 collections. (i.e. string vs ObjectId). You need to convert them to same datatype to perform the $lookup.
db.store.aggregate([
  {
    "$set": {
      "Tags": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$Tags",
          "as": "t",
          "in": {
            "$toObjectId": "$$t"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "tag",
      "localField": "Tags",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "TagResult"
    }
  }
])

Mongo Playground

Side note: if possible, refactor the schema to store the ids in the same datatype(i.e. either both ObjectIds or both strings) so you don't have to do the type conversion at run time.

Thank you so much. This solve my problem. I'm also looking into refactor my code to save it in the array as ObjectId. Thanks again for the help. Really really appreciate it.
